# Simplistic example for installing a software using master REST API for SaltStack

Tags: salt-stack

I am new to salt stack and trying my hands with it. I am trying to install a simplistic app say nginx on my minions using rest api.

I am able to ping my minions using following API call.

POST on https://x.x.x.x:8080 using following payload:

```
{
    "client" : "local",
    "tgt" : "*", 
    "fun" : "test.ping" 
}
```

On the similar line, I am looking for how to install a software on all of my minions. I couldn't find clear step in the documentation I looked at. Could someone help with this please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```json
{
    "client" : "local",
    "tgt" : "*", 
    "fun" : "pkg.install",
    "arg" : ["nginx"]
}
```

Reference:

- `pkg` execution module, which is a virtual module that gets translated into the proper, OS-specific package manager: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.pkg.html

  - Note that you can instead use a target execution module instead that is specific to your OS, such as `aptpkg` for debian-based systems using `apt`
- `rest_cherrypy` API documentation: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/netapi/all/salt.netapi.rest_cherrypy.html

  - Usage section, including more detailed examples: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/netapi/all/salt.netapi.rest_cherrypy.html#usage
- For more details on `local` client: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/clients/#salt.client.LocalClient

SaltStack also has an open source CLI tool for targeting the Salt API, called `pepper`, that you may find useful:

- PyPi / pip package: https://pypi.org/project/salt-pepper/

  - Source: https://github.com/saltstack/pepper

Also, here are some great resources to those new to SaltStack that may also be helpful for others. They are great places to ask questions, learn new content, hear directly from maintainers and other users, etc.

- [SaltStack Community Slack](https://saltstackcommunity.herokuapp.com/)
- [SaltStack IRC on Freenode](https://webchat.freenode.net/#salt)
- [SaltStack YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/SaltStack)
- [SaltStackInc Twitch channel](https://www.twitch.tv/saltstackinc)
- [SaltStack Email List](http://groups.google.com/group/salt-users)
- [Salt Community Events Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=saltstack.com_md73c3ufcs2eqbsmmnike4em80%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=America%2FNew_York)
- [Reddit: r/saltstack](https://www.reddit.com/r/saltstack/)